# What should my aspect ratio settings be for an Instagram ad?

Tags: video, aspect

I am trying to design a video for my ad in Instagram, but when I upload the video, it says:

1. Story media aspect ratio has to be smaller than or equal to 9:16
2. Aspect ratios of videos need to be 1:1.

What should be the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the ratio between the width and the height of the content (in pixels) should be the specified one.

Specifically, for a video you need to have an aspect ratio (technically, a DAR - display aspect ratio) of exactly 1:1, so the width of the video should be the same as the height of the video. In other words, the video should be square. As an example, 1000 pixels x 1000 pixels is fine, because (1000 / 1000) == 1.0, while 1280 x 720 is not, because the division is not 1.

For what they call "story media", the aspect ratio should not exceed 9:16 (which is 16:9 in vertical). In numbers, that's 0,5625. So in this case the "media" you're uploading shouldn't be exceeding that 0,5625 value, when calculating the ratio between the width and the height of the content.

Comment: As you recommened 1000*1000 I set that still it says it should be lesser than 9:16. and what is 0.5625? I didn't get that part.

Comment: Are you uploading a video? From what you posted in the original post I understand that the aspect ratio should be 1:1.
9:16 means that for every 9 horizontal pixels you have 16 vertical pixels. When you want to check if a video resolution satisfies a certain aspect ratio, you calculate the division between the width and the height of the video and you compare it with the aspect ratio. In this case 9:16 = 9 divided by 16 = 0,5625. When you export the video from your editor you should be able to set either the x:y aspect ratio or the calculated decimal number

Comment: Okay,still didn't get that. I am able to export it as x = 600 and y = 600 which is 600*600 = 1,that should work right?

Comment: It should, yes. Can you check if the output video file has the correct resolution? With something like [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo). Instagram should accept a video of 600x600 pixels without problems...

Comment: https://imgur.com/AZDXGH1 check this.

Comment: That's weird. Do you have any way of contacting Instagram about this issue? The video file seems correct to me, if the requirement is a 1:1 aspect ratio